# clients cannot establish connection after certain time even if the socket server is running

Tags: c#, sockets, console-application

I have a console application which acts as a socket server. It should accept data 24/7 from a number of clients, but issue is that the clients cannot establish connection after sometime (not constant). after closing & opening the connection works & it continues to next point of time.

Server

```
 public static void ExecuteServer()
        {
            int portNumber = 11111;
            string _responseMessageToClient = "";
            IPHostEntry ipHost = Dns.GetHostEntry(Dns.GetHostName());
            IPAddress ipAddr = ipHost.AddressList[0];
            IPEndPoint localEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(ipAddr, portNumber);

            // Creation TCP/IP Socket using  
            // Socket Class Costructor 
            Socket listener = new Socket(ipAddr.AddressFamily,
                         SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
            bool doBroadCast = false;

            try
            {
                listener.Bind(localEndPoint);

                listener.Listen(10);

                while (true)
                {
                    try`enter code here`
                    {
                        Socket clientSocket = listener.Accept();

                        // Data buffer 
                        byte[] bytes = new Byte[1024*2];//2048
                        string data = null;

                        while (true)
                        {

                            try
                            {
                                if (clientSocket.Connected)
                                {
                                    int numByte = clientSocket.Receive(bytes);

                                    data += Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytes,
                                                               0, numByte);
                                    if (data.IndexOf("!") > -1)
                                        break;
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    Console.WriteLine("Disconnected {0}", clientSocket.LocalEndPoint);
                                    break;
                                }
                            }
                            catch (Exception e)
                            {
                                //ErrorLogProvider.Save(e);
                                Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
                                break;
                            }
                        }

                        Console.WriteLine("Text received -> {0} ", data);
                        if (clientSocket.Connected)
                        {
                            clientSocket.Send(message);
                        }
                        clientSocket.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both);
                        clientSocket.Close();

                    }

                    catch (Exception e)
                    {
                    }
                }
            }

            catch (Exception e)
            {
            }
        }
```

> This server has to be running continuously - Client code given below

```
static void ExecuteClient()
    {

        try
        {

            // Establish the remote endpoint  
            // for the socket. This example  
            // uses port 11111 on the local  
            // computer. 
            int portNumber = 11111;
            IPHostEntry ipHost = Dns.GetHostEntry(Dns.GetHostName()); 
            IPAddress ipAddr = ipHost.AddressList[0];
            IPEndPoint localEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(ipAddr, portNumber);

            // Creation TCP/IP Socket using  
            // Socket Class Costructor 
            Socket sender = new Socket(ipAddr.AddressFamily,
                       SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
            long i = 0;

            try
            {

                //while (i < 10)
                //{
                // Connect Socket to the remote  
                // endpoint using method Connect() 
                sender.Connect(localEndPoint);

                // We print EndPoint information  
                // that we are connected 
                Console.WriteLine("Socket connected to -> {0} ",
                              sender.RemoteEndPoint.ToString());
                // Creation of messagge that 
                // we will send to Server 

                byte[] messageSent = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("^check!");
                int byteSent = sender.Send(messageSent);

                // Data buffer 
                byte[] messageReceived = new byte[1024];

                // We receive the messagge using  
                // the method Receive(). This  
                // method returns number of bytes 
                // received, that we'll use to  
                // convert them to string 
                int byteRecv = sender.Receive(messageReceived);
                Console.WriteLine("Message from Server -> {0}",
                      Encoding.ASCII.GetString(messageReceived,
                                                 0, byteRecv));
                //}
                // Close Socket using  
                // the method Close() 
                sender.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both);
                sender.Close();
            }

            // Manage of Socket's Exceptions 
            catch (ArgumentNullException ane)
            {

                Console.WriteLine("ArgumentNullException : {0}", ane.ToString());
            }

            catch (SocketException se)
            {

                Console.WriteLine("SocketException : {0}", se.ToString());
            }

            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Unexpected exception : {0}", e.ToString());
            }
        }

        catch (Exception e)
        {

            Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you provide some code?
Without seeing the code, it is rather difficult to spot an error.
There are so many things you could've done wrong. Without code it is almost impossible to give you any advice

Comment: Exception recieved in client

Socket Exception : ConnectionReset
System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (0x80004005): An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Receive(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size, SocketFlags socketFlags)

Comment: That's a start. Now we know the error/exception.
But it would be good to see your code.

Can you edit your question and paste the code of the server and the client?

Comment: Thanks. That's helpful
An advice: whenever you ask at SO, provide code. In 99% that's helpful. Let's see if I can help

Comment: Despite doing it in a way it shouldn't be done, this looks a bit weird. In the server you create a socket that listens on port 11111.
However the client connects to port 1111. That's not supposed to work at all I guess.

Comment: @Sheradil in client it is actually 11111. i have corrected the post

Comment: I don't have much time to find the error at home. Do you mind if I give you some  code that I have found sometime ago on SO that is working quite well for me?

With that one you can also handle multiple clients. Which won't work with your code if I am not mistaken. I will post the code in an actual answer in ~8 hours if you like

Comment: @Sheradil that would be of great help. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I've got this code somewhere from SO if I remember that correctly.
LoopClients just checks for new clients and handles them by spawning a new thread.

```
class Server {
    private TcpListener _server;
    private Boolean _isRunning = true;
    private int m_Port = 12001;
    private Thread m_ServerThread;

    public Server (int p_Port) {
        _server = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, m_Port);
        _server.Start( );            

        m_ServerThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(LoopClients));
        m_ServerThread.Start( );
    }

    public void ShutdownServer() {
        _isRunning = false;
    }

    public void LoopClients ( ) {
        while ( _isRunning ) {
            // wait for client connection
            TcpClient newClient = _server.AcceptTcpClient( );

            // client found.
            // create a thread to handle communication
            Thread t = new Thread(new ParameterizedThreadStart(HandleClient));
            t.Start(newClient);
        }
    }

    public void HandleClient (object obj) {
        try {
            // retrieve client from parameter passed to thread
            TcpClient client = (TcpClient) obj;

            // sets two streams
            StreamWriter sWriter = new StreamWriter(client.GetStream( ), Encoding.ASCII);
            StreamReader sReader = new StreamReader(client.GetStream( ), Encoding.ASCII);
            // you could use the NetworkStream to read and write, 
            // but there is no forcing flush, even when requested
            String sData = null;

            while ( client.Connected ) {
                sData = sReader.ReadToEnd( );
                if ( sData != "" )
                    break;
            }

            try {
                sWriter.WriteLine("test");
            } catch(Exception ex) {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            }

            sWriter.Dispose( );
            sReader.Dispose( );
            sWriter = null;
            sReader = null;
        } catch ( IOException ioe ) {

        }
    }
}
```

Client is somewhat shorter. I've got to shorten the code a bit here.
Client:

```
private void sendDataViaTCP () {
    TcpClient l_Client = new TcpClient();
    l_Client.Connect(IP, Port);
    Stream l_Stream = l_Client.GetStream( );
    StreamWriter l_SW = new StreamWriter(l_Stream);
    StreamReader l_SR = new StreamReader(l_SW.BaseStream);

    try {
        l_SW.WriteLine(Msg);
        l_SW.Flush( );

        String l_IncomingData;
        while ( ( l_IncomingData = l_SR.ReadToEnd()) != "") {                    
            AddLineToLog(l_IncomingData);
        }
    } finally {
        l_SW.Close( );
    }
}
```